# Overlapping Spring bean names with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have some sample code posted to github, so I won't include long code fragments here, please see for that: https://github.com/ralf-lackinger/spring-inheritance/tree/master

I have a `Parent` and a `Child`, both are Spring beans. When I want to retrieve the `Parent` via the `BeanFactory` by the bean's name, an instance of the `Child` is returned. This causes issues for me, since I want them to have different names and return only the specific, since the subclass overrides a method I use from the super class:

Parent names: parent, parentName1, parentName2
Child names: child, childName1, childName2

Short code sample, please see my github repository for the full code sample:
`context.getBean("parentName1", Parent.class).print();`
returns:
`Print from child.`

Maybe there is a solution to use qualifiers from Spring, but I'm not sure if this will work. I already tried the `@Primary` annotation, but didn't help me solve this issue.

I'm using:
java version "1.8.0_66"
Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE

EDIT:
I updated the github repository with a branch named 'fixed-name-conflict', where I included the changes I needed to make, to resolve my issue. See also the accepted answer (and the commons there) on more information.

Thanks @oailloud for his help.

EDIT 2:
The problematic parts were these methods:
`Parent:`

```
@Bean(name = {"parentName1", "parentName2"})
public Parent additionalBeanNames() {
    return new Parent();
}
```

and `Child`:

```
@Override
@Bean(name = {"childName1", "childName2"})
public Child additionalBeanNames() {
    return new Child();
}
```

Solutions was to rename to `Child`'s method, so the child does not pick up the `Parent`'s additional bean names.

Comment: This seems to be a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.  That doesn't mean it's automatically wrong - the principle may be more of a guideline than a hard and fast rule.  But it is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're overriding the method `additionalBeanNames` in your Child class. I guess Spring gets confused and creates a `Child` with the info from the Parent `@Bean`.
Just rename `additionalBeanNames()` method in your `Child` class and name explictly the beans with `@Bean(name="...")`.
And if you need to factorize code between these two methods, just extract it in a third protected method.

Also, watch out : you're creating two instances of each class. One because of the method annotated with `@Bean`, the other because of the `@Component`. In that case, the instance is named from the class name. That's why you have "parent" and "child" beans in your context.

Comment: I don't know the Spring source code too well, but if I had to make a guess, I would think that maybe they use reflection to find the annotations and that's why the `Child` gets the name from the `Parent`. But that wouldn't explain, why the `Parent` has also the additional names from the `Child` (and also the name from the `@Component` annotation).

Comment: I have just edited my answer : the @Component is normal, Spring will create a bean "parent" and a bean "child". You can rename them in the @Component value.     
The parent has not the names from the child. It's just that if you get all the `Parent` beans in the context, that will include the `Child` beans per inheritance.

Comment: I am aware that the `@Component` annotation had their own names, to get the additional names I used the 'bean lite mode' (as it is called in the Spring documenation).  
You are right with the `Parent` bean names, the child name comes from the context of all subclasses and the parent itself, so the `Parent` bean seems to behave as expected in my main-method. My bad I forgot about that. Thanks!  
  
But is there a way I can get the `Parent` for certain and not the `Child` by bean name?

Comment: I would go this way : change the name of `Child.additionalBeanNames()` so that  no `Child` gets "parentName1" as bean name and then get the `Parent` bean by its name ("parentName1" for instance).

Comment: This works and helps me resolve my issue, thank you. Please include you last comment also in your answer, I will accept it then. Again, thank you very much for you time and effort. If you have any links on where you have this information from, please include it also, so I have more references for further questions and learn more.

Comment: Done, you're welcome. Maybe you could include the `Child` and the `Parent` classes in your question (at least the `additionalBeanNames` methods) so the question is easily readable without going into GitHub ?